# Elasticsearch hits.total different with OR

Tags: elasticsearch

When I use the following search (`/posts/_search`) my hits.total is 1400:

```
{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Bitcoin"}}}
```

When I use the following search (`/posts/_search`) my hits.total is 500:

```
{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Ethereum"}}}
```

When I use an OR in my search, the `hits.total` is 1400, where I expected it to be 1900.

```
{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "(Ethereum) OR (Bitcoin)"}}}
```

Why is my hits.total number different when I am using an "OR"? I am using the hits.total as a counter to display and the number should be the same, right?

I am pretty new with ElasticSearch and hopefully, someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it Looks like there are **some documents where **_all** has both terms** i.e. Bitcoin and Ethereum, and hence, same documents get selected when u run the query independently, but when u run, this common documents get included only once.

May be this Venn diagram can explain better

[image]

A U B = (7+2+5) + (8+1+2+5) - (2+5) = 23

A + B = (7+2+5) + (8+1+2+5) = 30

If you are sure, these field which can never have multiple values then try adding "**default_field**" in the query and run the results. When you don't pass "**default_field**", if **defaults to index.query.default_field** index settings, which in turn **defaults to _all**.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "CRYPTOCURRENCY_TYPE",
      "query": "as"
    }
  }
}
```

More details you can be found here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes sense. I am using a 'full text' on content and I am trying to use the following query now: {"query_string": {"query": "Bitcoin OR Ethereum OR (Bitcoin AND Ethereum)"}}. But the result is the same. I will have a look in the docs if there are some other query types which could solve it. Will let you know when I found a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Adding (Bitcon AND Ethereum) will not change the result, what you get from (Bitcon OR Ethereum) as (Bitcon) will be true for Bitcoin and Bitcoin + anything else (i.e. Bitcon And Ethereum as well). So (Bitcon) alone includes the documents from Bitcoin And Ethereum too.